# How to choose a PM motor for its generation charcterstics?

Tags: power-supply, brushless-dc-motor, generator

I have to run a device that consumes 250Watt at 36V and now I have to power it using a generator.
Now I have 2 options for this:

1-BLDC motor (permanent magnet) which consumes at 24V @ 250Watt, max 360rpm
-https://robu.in/product/ebike-my1016z2-250w-360rpm-geared-dc-motor/

2-BLDC motor (permanent magnet) which consumes at 36V @ 240Watt, max 328rpm
-https://robu.in/product/240w-36v-brushless-hub-motor-for-e-bike/

Now which between the two options is more suitable option to be used as generator in the given condition of 36V @ 250Watt and why?
Links for both the motor provided if you want any other information.

I am not looking for the fact if it will produce less or more or somewhere near this. I just want to know which of the following will produce more power in comparison to each other.
Also one of them produce the same power at lower voltage and hence will it be difficult to consume the lower volt power at the condition which is higher provided above.

I am just looking for comparison and what basis this comparison is done.

Comment: Running a motor as a generator does not typically make for a good generator.  I don't think you're likely to get even close to 250W from a 250W motor and you don't get to choose the output voltage based on the input voltage.

Comment: The geared motor is probably a high RPM brushed motor. The hearing will very likely make it hard or worse to use as a generator.

Comment: The ebike motor should be usable. Voltage at rated RPM will be somewhat lower than for motor and power somewhat less. But it's a good starting point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [3-phase Brushless Motor - Are Volts and Amps at (X)RPM equal/similar when used as Generator?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/162771/3-phase-brushless-motor-are-volts-and-amps-at-xrpm-equal-similar-when-used-a)

Comment: In short : No, But you might get about 150W, 200W if you're lucky. See also https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/435462/how-to-measure-dc-motor-used-as-generator-efficiency-using-homebrew-methods https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/532630/how-will-a-motor-respond-as-a-generator/532658#532658 https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/177513/which-of-the-following-motors-best-suit-as-a-wind-generator/177584#177584